# Paraphrasing "compatible with"

Tags: paraphrasing

Are the sentences below equally transfer the same meaning?

The application is **compatible with** the devices.
The application **works/acts/operates on** the devices.
We **adapted the application/made the application adaptable** to the devices.

Comment: Just to check, do you want to know if all 6 possible sentences you have listed have the same meaning?

Comment: Yes, I do. Should I change "equally transfer the same meaning" to "have the same meaning"?

Comment: Yes, that would be the appropriate phrase here.

Comment: And I would also suggest removing the last set of sentences since it introduces a "we" that is not in either of the other sets of sentences. The last sentence set by default cannot have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phrases do not all have exactly the same meaning.

> The application is *compatible* with the devices.

Compatibility suggests an ideal pairing, that two things go together perfectly. This is probably the most popular way to say that software works with a particular piece of hardware and runs on it as well as expected.

> The application *works/<s>acts</s>/operates* on the devices.

"Acts on" is not idiomatic at all in this context.

Although not directly implied by the word, software can "work" to varying degrees. For example, it may run, but not optimally. I have heard people qualify such a statement by saying something like "it *works*, but not very well". So while at face-value this does mean something *functions*, it is not as reassuring as "compatible with".

"Operates on" I suppose *can* be used to describe software running on a piece of hardware, but as the software *platform* on which applications run is known as an "operating system" I think most people would avoid this term as it could be confusing.

> We adapted the application <s>/made the application adaptable</s> <s>to</s> *for* the devices.

You don't adapt a device to make it adaptable. It must have been adaptable in the first place in order for you to adapt it, so using the term "adaptable" is a mistake.

Saying you adapted the application *for* a device is the only one that implies you deliberately engineered the compatibility. Some software is compatible with hardware by pure chance - for example if you developed an application for Windows 7 and without any intervention it worked bug-free on Windows 10 you could say it was *compatible* with Windows 10, but you did not adapt it.